# Converting circular structure to JSON error

Tags: javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am trying to create a feature service from a feature collection. Prior to that, a query was performed and a featureSet was produced. However, I get the circular json error when I try to create a feature layer from the query results. Suggestions?

```
            mapServiceUrl= <map service>;
            var requestHandle = esriRequest({
        "url": dojo.replace("{0}/layers",[mapServiceUrl]),
        "content": {
          "f": "json"
        },
        "callbackParamName": "callback"
    });

   requestHandle.then(lang.hitch(this, function(response){
         dojo.forEach(response.layers, function(layerInfo) {                 
          console.log(layerInfo); //checking layer name            
        if(layerInfo.fields) {                 
          dojo.forEach(layerInfo.fields, function(fieldInfo) { 
                            console.log(fieldInfo); //checking fields               
          });  
        } 
        myfields =layerInfo.fields;         
    });      
         }));


    var featureCollection = {
      "layerDefinition": null,
      "featureSet": {
        "features": [],
        "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint"
      }
    };

    layerDefinition = {
      "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
      "objectIdField": "ObjectID",          
      "field": [myfields]
    };


     var featureCollection = {
        layerDefinition: layerDefinition,
        featureSet: featureSet 
        };  
    var thislayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(featureCollection);    
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same error trying to create a FeatureCollection from a RouteResult.  The root cause is that the features in the FeatureSet returned by the task contain extra properties that reference other task properties, leading to the circular structure.

In your case it's likely that the `fields` object has similar circular references. Rather than using `layerInfo.fields` directly, iterate over the Fields array and create your own `Field` objects.